# Dart: convert decimal to hex

Tags: dart

I've been searching for a way to convert decimal numbers to hexadecimal format in the Dart programming language.

The `hex.encode` method in the `HexCodec` class, for example, cannot convert the decimal 1111 (which has a hex value of 457) and instead gives an exception:

> FormatException: Invalid byte 0x457. (at offset 0)

How do I convert a decimal number to hex?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
 int.toRadixString(16)
```

does that.

See also https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/m/#!topic/misc/ljkYEzveYWk

Comment: If you want to have a fixed-width hex string, you can also use `int.toRadixString(16).padLeft(4, '0')` to  ensure (at least) four digits.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a little fuller example:

```dart
final myInteger = 2020;
final hexString = myInteger.toRadixString(16);      // 7e4
```

The radix just means the base, so `16` means base-16. You can use the same method to make a binary string:

```dart
final binaryString = myInteger.toRadixString(2);    // 11111100100
```

If you want the hex string to always be four characters long then you can pad the left side with zeros:

```dart
final paddedString = hexString.padLeft(4, '0');     // 07e4
```

And if you prefer it in uppercase hex:

```dart
final uppercaseString = paddedString.toUpperCase(); // 07E4
```

Here are a couple other interesting things:

```dart
print(0x7e4); // 2020

int myInt = int.parse('07e4', radix: 16);
print(myInt); // 2020
```